# Bukkit staff wands plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have made a plugin that adds the commend `/staffwands`. It will give a stick, which is for a staff. It is a wand plugin.

But I want to make sure that if normal players in the game just get a stick it won't be a wand, only if you do `/staffwands` it will be a wand. I've made a class with the permissions and the wand, I just need help on this. Here is the code, if you could help with any suggestions, that'll be great:

```
package me.capz.stick;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;    
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;    
import org.bukkit.EntityEffect;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Egg;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class stick extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("StaffWand")) {
            if(!sender.hasPermission("StaffWand.staff")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Only Staff can use this!");
                if(sender.hasPermission("StaffWand.staff")) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Here is your staff wand!");
                    ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.STICK);
                    ((Player)sender).getInventory().addItem(item); return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;               
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        if (!(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)) return;

        if (!(e.getItem().getType() == Material.STICK)) return;

        Egg egg = e.getPlayer().launchProjectile(Egg.class);
        egg.setFireTicks(20);

        if(!(player.getInventory().contains(Material.MAGMA_CREAM)))return;
        player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(Material.MAGMA_CREAM));
        if(!player.getInventory().contains(Material.MAGMA_CREAM))return;
        player.sendMessage("Magma_Cream needed!");
        egg.setBounce(true);
        egg.playEffect(EntityEffect.HURT);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
        if (e.getDamager() instanceof Egg) {
            Egg egg = (Egg) e.getDamager();
            if (egg.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player shooter = (Player) egg.getShooter();
                if (shooter.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.STICK) {
                    e.setDamage(10.0);  
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved code inside a code block by selecting the code and then using ctrl-K. Also removed a bunch of empty lines from the code example.

Comment: I don't get your onComand(): inside `!sender.hasPermission()` block you put `sender.hasPermission()`. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add some type of metadata to the `ItemStack`. I would recommend adding lore, as it is impossible to change:

```
ItemStack wand = new ItemStack(Material.STICK); //create the ItemStack
ItemMeta meta = wand.getItemMeta(); //get the ItemMeta

List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>(); //create a List<String> for the lore
lore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Staff Wand"); //add "§7Staff Wand" to the lore

meta.setLore(lore); //set the ItemMeta's lore to the List<String>
wand.setItemMeta(meta); //set the ItemStack's meta.
```

Then, you could check if the stick is a *Staff Wand* by checking if the lore equals the above lore:

```
public boolean isStaffWand(ItemStack item){
  //make sure the item is not null, it is a stick, it has item meta, and it has lore
  //to avoid a NullPointerException
  if(item != null && item.getType().equals(Material.STICK) && item.hasItemMeta() && item.getItemMeta().hasLore()){

    List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();//create the lore List<String>
    lore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Staff Wand");//add "§7Staff Wand" to the lore
    //this lore is now the same as the lore created in the above code block

    //check if the item's lore equals the lore above
    if(item.getItemMeta().getLore().equals(lore)){
      return true; //"item" is a Staff Wand
    }
  }
  return false; //"item" is not a Staff Wand
}
```